# Prove that $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\zeta(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n \in \mathbb N$.

I was asked to write $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{n+1}}$ in terms of $\zeta(n+1)$

My conjecture is that $$(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\zeta(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{n+1}}$$

I'm puzzled since I can't prove it... Using that $\zeta(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{n+1}} $ led me nowhere. I tried summation by parts. I don't know how to deal with $2^{-n}$. Am I supposed to rewrite it as the limit of a series and use Cauchy product ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** How can you simply
$$ \left( \frac{1}{1^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \cdots \right) - 2 \left( \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{6^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{8^{n+1}} \cdots \right) $$
in two ways?